# How to load a particular content in a codeigniter view without full page refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I have a View where i get the contents dynamically with the pagination, per page 20 records when i click on pagination it gets the next 20 records with respect to page number, but my whole page refreshes itself after every pagination request. So i want  particular section to load dynamically.How can i achieve this with the div tag, means particular contents within the div tag should get loaded dynamically. Below is my view page : Kindly help me

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <h2 class="title-divider"><?php echo $page_heading; ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <!--Blog Roll Content-->
<!--I want only the below content(div) should get refreshed with a pagination request-->
      <div class="span9 blog-roll blog-list"> 
        <?php if(!empty($newsArray)) { foreach($newsArray as $result){ ?>
        <!-- Blog post -->
        <div class="media row-fluid">
          <div class="span1 hidden-phone"> 
            <!-- Date desktop -->
            <div class="date-wrapper"> <span class="date-m"><?php echo $result['monthName']; ?></span> <span class="date-d"><?php echo $result['day']; ?></span> <span class="date-y"><?php echo $result['year']; ?></span></div>
          </div>
          <div class="span11">
            <div class="media-body">
              <h4 class="title media-heading"><a href="<?php echo base_url('news/detail/'.$result['ID']); ?>"><?php echo $result['TTL']; ?></a></h4>
              <div class="tag"></div>
              <ul class="inline meta muted">
                <li><i class="icon-user"></i><?php echo $result['SRC']; ?></li>
                <!-- Meta details mobile -->
                <li><span class="visible-phone"><i class="icon-calendar"></i> <span class="visible-desktop">Created:</span><?php echo $result['day_letter']; echo ' '; echo $result['day']; ?><sup><?php echo $result['daySup']; ?></sup> <?php echo $result['monthName']; echo ' '; echo $result['year']; ?></span></li>
              </ul>
              <p><?php if(!empty($result['CNTNT']))echo $result['CNTNT'].' ...'; ?></p>
              <ul class="inline links">
                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('news/detail/'.$result['ID']); ?>" class="btn btn-mini"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i> Read more</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
         <?php echo $links; ?>
        </div>
        <?php  }else { ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-error">
                        <h4>No News Found!</h4>
                    </div>  
            <?php } ?> 
     </div>
         <!--Sidebar-->
      <div class="span3 sidebar sidebar-right">
            <?php 
            $this->load->view('news/news_sidebar');
            ?>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.container--> 
</div>
<!--#content-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the AJAX Pagination Class, on Github.

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/AJAX-Pagination-with-CI-Pagination-Library

Comment: Hi i am using the above link to create pagination. I am not getting how to set my

Comment: Please help me me not getting the page parameter in the url, Everytime i have same set of records me not getting any value in $page in controller $page = $this->input->post('page');

Answer (score 1):

```
     Using templates and pagination I am not able to achieve the same, instead i have used ajax GET request to pull the data for the page in pagination links, and embed it into corresponding div tag.
```

For example in your case add a new div surrounding the block of code.

```
 <div id="new">
        <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
               <?php echo $links; ?>
        </div>
        <?php  }else { ?>

        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <h4>No News Found!</h4>
        </div>

        <?php } ?> 
 </div>
```

Suppose you have a region for this in your template say content.

For your view handle click events on the anchor links in pagination view. call an ajax get request to the url where pagination is handled say (kLinkPageURL=records/paginationHandle/).

```
function configure(){
    $('#link a').click(function(){
        href =  $(this).attr("href");
        categoryId = href.split("/");
        loadPageLink(categoryId[1], categoryId[2]);
     });
}

function  loadPageLink(categoryId, page){
        var url = kLinkPageURL + '/' + categoryId + '/' + page;
        $.ajax({
                'url' : url,
                'type': 'GET',
                'success': function(data) {
                        $('#listContainer').html(data);
                        configure();
                }
        });  
}
```

we need to handle base_url and uri_segment in paginationHandle controller function. 
Now base_url should be such that clicking pagination link does not redirect but we can identify page number and the records identity, I have used (#/recordId). page number is assigned to the href for anchors in link while create_links.

uri_segment is used in pagination library, identify correct uri_segment in your paginationHandle.

Now in your controller only call template->write_view for the content region.
it will return the data for the page such as information for 20 records on this page.

you can push this data to new division in this way $("new").html(data);